image.select is not a function in earth engine
this is a js code of generating time series data from google earth engine. I'm trying to extract the width of river.
I'm trying to run this on earth engine to get the time series data, but i'm getting error :
Image.select is not a function.
the code is:

var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[
      [74.36670, 32.79014],
      [74.36670, 30.67386],
      [76.81411, 30.67386],
      [76.81411, 32.79014]
    ]]
  );
  
// Define start and end points for the river
var start_point = ee.Geometry.Point([74.36670, 32.79014]);
var end_point = ee.Geometry.Point([76.81411, 30.67386]);

// Create a line between the start and end points
var river_path = ee.Geometry.LineString([start_point.coordinates(), end_point.coordinates()]);

// Function to generate points at 50 km intervals along the river
var generate_points_along_river = function(river, interval_km) {
  var length = river.length();
  var num_intervals = length.divide(interval_km * 1000).int();
  var points = ee.List.sequence(0, num_intervals).map(function(i) {
    return river.cutLines(ee.Number(i).multiply(interval_km).multiply(1000));
  }).flatten();
  return ee.FeatureCollection(points.map(function(point) {
    return ee.Feature(point);
  }));
};

// Generate points along the river at 50 km intervals
var interval_km = 50;
var points_fc = generate_points_along_river(river_path, interval_km);

// Function to create a perpendicular line (cross-section) at each point
var create_cross_section = function(feature) {
  var coords = feature.geometry().coordinates();
  var x = ee.Number(coords.get(0));
  var y = ee.Number(coords.get(1));
  var offset = 0.05;  // Adjust the offset distance as needed
  
  // Create perpendicular line
  var line = ee.Geometry.LineString([
    [x.subtract(offset), y.subtract(offset)], 
    [x.add(offset), y.add(offset)]
  ]);
  return ee.Feature(line);
};

var cross_sections = points_fc.map(create_cross_section);

// Function to mask clouds using the quality band for Landsat 8 and 9
var mask_clouds = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5).eq(0);
  var cloud_shadow = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3).eq(0);
  return image.updateMask(cloud.and(cloud_shadow));
};

// Function to mask clouds using the quality band for Landsat 5 and 7
var mask_clouds_ls5_ls7 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4).eq(0);
  var cloud_shadow = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 2).eq(0);
  return image.updateMask(cloud.and(cloud_shadow));
};

// Function to calculate NDWI
var calculate_ndwi = function(image) {
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B5']).rename('NDWI');
  return image.addBands(ndwi);
};

// Function to get the monthly collection
var get_monthly_collection = function(start_date, end_date) {
  var landsat5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
    .map(mask_clouds_ls5_ls7)
    .map(calculate_ndwi);
  var landsat7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
    .map(mask_clouds_ls5_ls7)
    .map(calculate_ndwi);
  var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
    .map(mask_clouds)
    .map(calculate_ndwi);
  var landsat9 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
    .map(mask_clouds)
    .map(calculate_ndwi);
  return landsat5.merge(landsat7).merge(landsat8).merge(landsat9);
};

// Generate monthly collections
var start_year = 1995;
var end_year = 2023;
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12).map(function(m) {
  return ee.Number(m).format('%02d');
});

var monthly_collections = ee.List.sequence(start_year, end_year).map(function(year) {
  return months.map(function(month) {
    var start_date = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, 1);
    var end_date = start_date.advance(1, 'month');
    var collection = get_monthly_collection(start_date, end_date);
    return collection.median().set('system:time_start', start_date.millis());
  });
}).flatten();

// Function to measure width at cross-sections
var measure_width = function(image) {
  var get_width = function(feature) {
    var buffer = feature.geometry().buffer(500);  // Adjust buffer as necessary
    var water_pixels = image.select('NDWI').gt(0).clip(buffer).reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(), geometry: buffer, scale: 30
    }).get('NDWI');
    return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), {'width': water_pixels});
  };
  return cross_sections.map(get_width);
};

// Apply the width measurement function to each monthly NDWI image
var widths_time_series = monthly_collections.map(function(image) {
  return measure_width(image);
});

// Flatten the collection of widths to export
var widths_flat = ee.FeatureCollection(widths_time_series).flatten();

// Export the widths time series data
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: widths_flat,
  description: 'Satluj_River_Widths_Time_Series',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

// Visualize NDWI and cross-sections for the first month (as an example)
var ndwi_image = ee.Image(monthly_collections.get(0)).clip(aoi);
var ndwi_vis = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['00FFFF', '0000FF']};

Map.centerObject(aoi, 8);
Map.addLayer(ndwi_image.select('NDWI'), ndwi_vis, 'NDWI');
Map.addLayer(aoi, {}, 'AOI');
Map.addLayer(points_fc, {}, 'Points');
Map.addLayer(cross_sections, {}, 'Cross Sections');

can anyone please explain why this is occured and what is the soln for this... i didn't understand what is the problem...

duplicate question with these (unanswered!) questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65185339/error-select-sampleregions-is-not-a-function-how-to-solve-it and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984413/image-selectbands-sampleregions-is-not-a-function-error-what-must-i-do

This happens because currently, the code "does not know" that the argument image of your measure_width function is an ee.Image object. You need to "tell" it explicitly by casting it using ee.Image(image):
var water_pixels = ee.Image(image).select('NDWI').gt(0).clip(buffer).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(), geometry: buffer, scale: 30
}).get('NDWI');

This should solve the specific error you are facing.
